# gitlab: How to get notified by web hook when a tag added?

Tags: gitlab, githooks, webhooks

I set up a 'push' hook, but it only got triggered by a commit pushed but not work for tag added, how to get that worked?

Answer (score 0):

You could review [issue 2128](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2128), which was precisely about that feature (webhook for a tag).

Depending on the version of GitLab, it may have evolved (or it need to be re-opened).

Comment: I'm running 6.4.3, still got the problem

Answer (score 0):

In upstream version [project hooks are triggered only with branch push (not tags)](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/services/git_push_service.rb#L34-L37)

You can change this [like](https://github.com/zzet/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/services/git_push_service.rb#L54-L55)